# Not receiving expected output from unit test on hash in perl

Tags: perl, unit-testing, methods, return-type

I have integrate my tests with other tests and my error hash and it's method(s) are not outputting the correct/expected outputs. My new() method now also has an      `ìs_error` check so I think it may be something to do with the output of my new method. 
The new() method accepts an error hash with/without arguments or an error string with/without arguments. It accepts `code`as its first argument (which is then deleted and replaced by the error hash or string itself. (Well that's what I'm trying to achieve.

So I'll show you the code now.

Error.pm

```
package ASC::Builder::Error;

  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use parent 'Exporter';
  our @EXPORT_OK = qw/new/;

  # Method for creating error message
  sub new {
      my ($class, %args) = @_;
      # Takes code in as an argument and then removes it so the error hash it self can be assigned to it
      my $self = delete $args{code};
      #my $error = %args{0};
      if (is_error($self)) {
          return $self;
      }
      # 1st argument will be error hash. Any other arguments will be context params & inserted into
      # context field of the error hash
      my @args = keys %args;
      if (ref $self eq 'HASH' && (@args > 1)) {
          foreach my $key (@{ $self->{context} } ) {
              # And take the ones we need
              $self->{args}->{$key} = $args{$key};
         }
         my @template_args = map { $self->{args}->{$_} } @{ $self->{context} };

         # Map/Insert arguments into context hash and insert into string template
         $self->{message} = sprintf ($self->{template}, @template_args);
         return bless $self, $class;
      }
      # Supporting the old error messaage (string & parameters)
      else {
           return bless { message => %args } , $class;
      }
  }

  # Accessor for category
  sub category {
      return shift->{category};
  }

  # Accessor for message
  sub template {
      return shift->{template};
  }
  # Accessor for context
  sub context {
      return shift->{context};
  }
# Accessor for template option
  sub tt {
      return shift->{tt}{template};
  }
  # Accessor for fatal
  sub is_fatal {
      return shift->{fatal};
  }
  # Setter for is_fatal
  sub set_is_fatal {
      my ($self, $fatal) = @_;
      $self->{fatal} = $fatal;
  }

  # Accessor for wiki_page
  sub wiki_page {
      return shift->{wiki_page};
  }
  # Accessor for args. args are a hash ref of context parameters that are
  # passed in as a list at construction
  sub args {
      return shift->{args};
  }
  # Accessor for error message which is processed inside the new() method.
  # Will return error message with context parameters inserted.
  sub message {
      return shift->{message};

  }
  # Stringifies the error to a log message (for SB dashboard), including the
  # category, message, and wiki_page.
  sub stringify {
      my ($self) = @_;
      return sprintf ("%s: %s\nMore info: %s",$self->{category}, $self->{message}, $self->{wiki_page});
  }

  # Accessor for old error message type
  sub details {
      my $self = shift;
      return $self->{details} || $self->{message};
  }
  sub code {
      return shift->{code};
  }
 # Used to deserializ from build json.
  sub recreate_from_hash {
      my($class, $hash) = @_;
      return bless $hash, $class;
  }

  # Use to check if something is out error.
  sub is_error {
      if (scalar(@_) > 1) { # Called as $class->is_error
          shift; # Get rid of class
      }
      return UNIVERSAL::isa(shift, 'ASC::Builder::Error');
  }
  1;
```

Type.pm

```
package ASC::Builder::Error::Type;
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use parent 'Exporter';

  # Export the list of errors
  our @EXPORT_OK = qw/
  UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR
  code
  /;
  # List of error message
use constant code => {
   use constant {
      CABLING_CHECK_TOR_INCORRECT_CABLING_ERROR => {
          category => 'Cabling Error',
          template => "ToR cabling is not correct at T1.The uplinks must be cabled to exactly one t1 device group",
          tt => { template => 'disabled'},
          fatal => 1,
          wiki_page =>'http://w.error-fix.com/index.php/Builder/ErrorCodes/CABLING_CHECK_TOR_CABLING_INCORRECT_ERROR',
      },
      UPDATE_IMAGE_ERROR => {
          category => 'Imaging Error',
          template => "Cannot determine switch model",
          tt => { template => 'disabled'},
          fatal => 1,
          wiki_page =>'http://w.error-fx.com/index.php/Builder/ErrorCodes/UPDATE_IMAGE_ERROR',
      },
      UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR => {
          category => 'Connection Error',
          template => "Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds.",
          context => [ qw(switch_ip  timeout) ],
          tt => {template => 'disabled'},
          fatal => 1,
          wiki_page => 'http://w.error-fix.com/index.php/Builder/ErrorCodes/UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR',
      },
      UNKNOWN_CLIENT_CERT_ID_ERROR => {
          category => 'Services Error',
          template => "Unknown client certificate id: %s",
          context => qw(cert_id),
          tt => { template => 'disabled'},
          fatal => 1,
          wiki_page =>'http://w.error-fix.com/index.php/Builder/ErrorCodes/',
      },
  # Add errors to this library
  };
  1;
```

Error.t

```
  use lib ('./t/lib');
  use strict;
  no strict 'refs';
  use warnings;

  use ASC::Builder::Error;
  use ASC::Builder::Error::Type;

  use Test::More;
  use Test::Exception;
  use LWP::Simple 'head'; # Used to test if wiki link is giving a response

  test_functionality_of_old_error();
  test_functionality_of_new_error();
  test_correctness_of_type_pm();

  sub test_functionality_of_old_error {
     # Example runtime parameters
     my $switch_ip = '192.192.0.0';
     my $timeout = '30';

      # Correct case
      {
          my $error = ASC::Builder::Error->new(sprintf 'Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds', $switch_ip, $timeout);
          ok(ASC::Builder::Error->is_error($error), 'Should detect error');
          isa_ok ($error, 'ASC::Builder::Error');
          is($error->message, 'Could not ping switch 192.192.0.0 in 30 seconds');
      };
  };



  sub test_functionality_of_new_error {
      my $example_error = {
          category => 'Connection Error',
          template => 'Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds.',
          context => [ qw(switch_ip  timeout) ],
          tt => {template => 'disabled'},
          fatal => 1,
          wiki_page => 'http://w.error-fix.com/index.php/Builder/ErrorCodes/UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR',
      };

      # Correct case
      {
          my $error = ASC::Builder::Error->new( code => $example_error, timeout => 30, switch_ip => '192.192.0.0' );

          isa_ok ($error, 'ASC::Builder::Error');
 can_ok ($error, 'category');
          is ($error->category(), 'Connection Error', 'Return the correct category');

          can_ok ($error, 'template');
          is ($error->template(), 'Could not ping switch %s in %s seconds.', 'Return the correct category');

          can_ok ($error, 'tt');
          is ($error->tt(), 'disabled', 'Return the correct tt template');

          can_ok ($error, 'context');
          is_deeply($error->context(), ['switch_ip', 'timeout'], 'Return the correct context params');

          can_ok ($error, 'is_fatal');
          ok($error->is_fatal(), 'Return the correct value');

          can_ok ($error, 'message');
          is ($error->message(), 'Could not ping switch 192.192.0.0 in 30 seconds.', 'Return the correct message');

          can_ok ($error, 'stringify');
          is ($error->stringify(), "Connection Error: Could not ping switch 192.192.0.0 in 30 seconds.\nMore info: http://w.error-fix.com/index.php/Builder/ErrorCodes/                     UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR", 'stringify creates the correct message');

  };

      # Too many arguments (this is okay)
      lives_ok( sub { ASC::Builder::Error->new( code => $example_error, timeout => 1, switch_ip => 2, extra => 3 ) }, 'Creating with too many arguments lives. (allows for additional         context string to be added in the code)' );
      };

      sub test_correctness_of_type_pm {

  # These test cases contain all the errors from Type.pm
      my @test_cases = (
          {
              name => 'UNABLE_TO_PING_SWITCH_ERROR',
              args => {
                  switch_ip => '192.192.0.0',
                  timeout => 30,
              },
              message => 'Could not ping switch 192.192.0.0 in 30 seconds.',
          },
      );
    foreach my $t (@test_cases) {
         subtest $t->{name} => sub {
            no strict 'refs'; # Because we need to use variable to get to a constant
            ASC::Builder::Error::Type->import($t->{name});

            # Create the Error object from the test data
            # Will also fail if the name was not exported by Type.pm
            my $error;
            lives_ok( sub { $error = ASC::Builder::Error->new(code => &{ $t->{name} },%{ $t->{args} }) }, 'Error can be created');

            # See if it has the right values
            is ($error->message, $t->{message}, 'Error message is correct');

            # Using LWP::Simple to check if the wiki page link is not broken
            # ok head($error->wiki_page); #CANT'T GET THIS TEST TO WORK


          }
      }
  };
  done_testing;
```

Here is the unit tests I am trying to add. They all seem to pass except the last one:

```
sub test_error_misc {
      ok(ASC::Builder::Error->is_error(ASC::Builder::Error->new("I'll be back")), "Should detect our error");
      ok(!ASC::Builder::Error->is_error("I'll be back"), "Should not detect string");
      ok(!ASC::Builder::Error->is_error({ message => "I'll be back" }), "Should not detect hash");
      ok(ASC::Builder::Error->new("I'll be back"));
      is(ASC::Builder::Error->new(ASC::Builder::Error->new("I'll be back"))->message(),"I'll be back", "Should return the provided argument");
  }
```

I think it's something got to do with the return value of the `is_error` method being called inside `new`. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
#Test Output:

#   Failed test 'Should return the provided argument'
#   at t/01_general_errors.t line 33.
#          got: 'ASC::Builder::Error=HASH(0x7fbe4bbd5220)'
#     expected: 'I'll be back'
```

Comment: What do you get when you Dumper `ASC::Builder::Error->new(ASC::Builder::Error->new("I'll be back"))`?

Comment: Where should I add the test_error_misc? When I created the file structure, I got errors in the Type.pm: `"use" not allowed in expression at ASC/Builder/Error/Type.pm line 13, near ""`

Comment: That is strange @choroba. I'll check that now. But @simbabque , I ran a diag explain on that line and received the following `# bless( {
#   '' => undef,
#   'message' => 'I\'ll be back'
# }, 'ASC::Builder::Error' )`

Comment: Hmm. adding `sub` before the `{` fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `is_error` check is on the `code` argument provided to the constructor

```
  my $self = delete $args{code};
  if (is_error($self)) {
      return $self;
  }
```

but you don't provide a `code` argument in your test

```
is(ASC::Builder::Error->new(ASC::Builder::Error->new("I'll be back"))->message(),...);
```

The last line should probably be

```
is(ASC::Builder::Error->new(
      code => ASC::Builder::Error->new("I'll be back")), ...);
```

and you should have gotten a warning about initializing a hash with an odd number of elements. (You do `use warnings` all the time, don't you?)

Comment: I am trying to run the is_error check on the error hash (or string) , which follows the code argument. I thought be deleting the code argument, the error itself is automatically moved forward into the position of `code`.  How would I do this? if this is not the case?

Comment: `%args` is a hash and key-value pairs in a hash do not have a "position". It sounds like sometimes you want to receive the arguments to your constructor as a hash and sometimes you want to receive them as a list. That can be done but it might also mean that you should rethink your design.

Comment: Okay, so would do you think this work better if I used an array, so in that way when I remove `code` and can shift the next element to the first positon of the array, and then run `is_error` on the that element of the array. Does that make sense at all?

Comment: Not to me. If sometimes you want to pass an existing error object to your constructor, how about you prefix it with another key like `error => ...` to be consistent?

Comment: @PaulRussell If you want to be able to call constructor with (1) either a hash (2) or hashref and a hash, see the end of my answer to your previous question.  Also see a comment. Or straighten invocations of `new` throughout to always just use a hash,  as [mob](http://stackoverflow.com/users/168657/mob) says, which is a cleaner design.